# Assigning value to ptr in struct (C)

Tags: c

I have declared a structure in my .h file, as such:

```
struct node{
char* string;
}
```

I intend this to have created a structure, example, with one member, a character pointer named string.

Now, I figure out how long the string is and malloc an array of appropriate size, taking the input with that.

```
char* test;
test = (char*) malloc( n * sizeof(char) );
```

Insofar as I am aware, this has created character pointer test, and has assigned it to point at the head of the array I just malloc'd. I then proceed to assign each array slot to a character that the user has entered, and I read it back out - this all compiles and works appropriately. My problem comes when I try to assign this character pointer to the character pointer in a structure node passed in to this structure, as:

```
int f1( struct node* new ){
```

So I try to assign the pointer in the structure to the value of the pointer to the array, like so:

```
new->string = test;
```

But I segfault.

To me, this seems like I am assigning a char* to something that expects a char* so this should be working fine...I'm probably missing something stupid, but does anyone have a direction to point me in? Thanks much!

Comment: Does `new` point to an allocated (stack or dynamic, take your pick) `struct node` ? Even if `test` is a bogus pointer, that assignment statement will not cause a seg-fault unless `new` is invalid.

Comment: Off topic, but don't name variables `new` or you'll confuse c++ programmers.

Comment: Using "new" as identifier isn't a good idea if you ever want to port to C++.

Comment: I thought so - I declare struct u_acct *new; in the main function and pass *new into the function this is in...but I could be mistaken.

Comment: ah okay good to know about naming conventions, thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your caller of `f1()` and make sure your parameter is **valid**.

This will work:

```
struct node *you = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
if (you)
{
    f1(you);
    free(you);
}
```

As will this:

```
struct node me;
f1(&me);
```

**This will NOT work**

```
struct node *me;
int f1(me);
```

Comment: ...talk about missing the little things. I can't believe I did that >_< thank you so much!

Comment: @AustinLeigh happens more often than you think.

Answer (score 0):

Some observations to note:

1. `sizeof(char)` is one by definition.
2. Recommended way of calling `malloc` is one that avoids casts as well as gets sizeof to infer the type from the pointer being allocated.  (See below)
3. Avoid using names such as `new` for your identifiers (to the extent possible).
4. Remember to `free` the `string` member within `node` when you are done.

To elaborate #2, see below --

```
struct MyType *foo;
foo = malloc( n * sizeof *foo ); /* allocate n elements where n > 0 */
```

For some reason, if you chose foo to be of some other type, the `malloc` call is one less line for you to worry about.  Also, should you forget to include stdlib.h, the compiler will let you know about it.